# Have i lost my changes after using Revert?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I made some changes to a few files within VS 2019.

I added a comment and clicked Commit All under Git Changes tab (didnt do a Push).

I realised i made a mistake by including some temp files so i clicked Revert under Git Repository Explorer against the comment i made.

All my changes have been lost in VS 2019..... Is there anyway to recover my changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to resolve this after panicking a bit!! Just in case this helps anyone

- Clicked Git in the VS 2019 menu.
- View Branch History.
- Under Local History, i right clicked the row where i made the changes and added my comment.
- Selected Revert > accepted the warning

All my work was restored. I then continued to do the usual Commit and Push which then pushed my changes to the repo and i was able to verify that.